# Betta eats great but just lays at the bottom of the tank!

Tags: betta

Okay so I have had my tank for about 3 or 4 months and 
Thomas bubbles has always been active and social, but for the past week he is just laying at the bottom and rarely swims around. He still eats great, I cycle the water 20% every week in his 2.5 gallon tank. I have tried to give him a ping pong ball to play with for boredom but he just doesn't seem his self. He doesn't look like he has ich,velvet,or fin rot. The only questionable physical condition I see is maybe is top fin is clamped a little I cant tell. What am I missing. the ph level has been a little high and I have been struggle a little to get it down, but I don't think it has been to high to long to hurt him to bad yet. Could this be the main problem or what should I be trying to do. He is my families only pet, and we love him dearly. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the temperature. Bettas like 78 to 80 degrees F. Colder temperatures make them less active. Good Luck!